# AWS erroring about time difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am calling aws with async call and I'm getting this. `<![CDATA["Signature expired: 20171114T190104Z is now earlier than 20180323T213705Z (20180323T214205Z - 5 min.)"]]>`.

sI know that this is most likely caused by my machine having the clock off, but how do I fix it? The time is set to be determine automatically like so.
[image]

I'm using Fedora.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsignatureexception) answer suggested that the AWS keys might be timing out(?) (I don't fully understand this one). If that's the case how do I fix this? I tried manually changing my clock both -5min and +5min, as suggested by the error, but it didn't do anything.

Edit: The same error appears when using a live heroku server.

Edit2: I'm using Node Express and making the call like this:

```
function(callback) {
  // third call
  var results = '';
  var options = {
    host: urlObject.host,
    protocol: urlObject.protocol,
    path: urlObject.path,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=key/20171114/us-west-1/awis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=key`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
      'X-Amz-Date': '20171114T190104Z',
      Accept: 'application/xml',
    },
  };
  https.get(options, resource => {
    resource.setEncoding('utf8');
    resource.on('data', function(data) {
      // results += JSON.parse(data);
      results += data;
    });
    resource.on('end', function() {
      callback(null, results);
    });
    resource.on('error', function(err) {
      callback(err);
    });
  });
},
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with your clock.  You have hard-coded November 14, 2017 in two places in your code. Why?

Comment: That's the example code from their documentation. How else would I do it?

Comment: You set it to the actual, current time and date that you used when calculating the signature.

Comment: Something like `DateTime.Now()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to provide the current date using the `X-Amz-Date` header, not the date from the example code. This [blog post](https://virtualbrakeman.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/aws-rest-api-authentication-using-node-js/) has an example of how to do that in Node.js to follow the format that the AWS API expects:

```
// get the various date formats needed to form our request
var amzDate = getAmzDate(new Date().toISOString());

// this function converts the generic JS ISO8601 date format to the specific format the AWS API wants
function getAmzDate(dateStr) {
  var chars = [":","-"];
  for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
    while (dateStr.indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {
      dateStr = dateStr.replace(chars[i],"");
    }
  }
  dateStr = dateStr.split(".")[0] + "Z";
  return dateStr;
}
```

Then, of course, you'll want to assign that `amzDate` variable to the `X-Amz-Date` header in your request.

Long term, I think you'll find it is more useful to use the official [Node.js AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) instead of trying to custom-make these queries to the format that AWS expects, so you may want to explore that!

Comment: Ok thanks. The blog post helped. Now I need to get my client to tell me the url for the bucket and it should work. Thanks!