# AWS Lambda Layers: Failed to create layer version: Signature expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My binary zip file is 40mb and after waiting for it to upload on AWS Lambda Layers I was encountered with the following message:

```
Failed to create layer version: Signature expired: 20190527T140335Z is now earlier than 20190527T140411Z (20190527T140911Z - 5 min.)
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve this without uploading to S3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsignatureexception

Comment: Why not upload it to s3? 40mb is very close to the 50mb limit, and you will have to do it anyway at some point because of this limit

Answer (score 0):

ended up just uploading to s3 bucket, seems like theres no way around it.