# AWS beanstalk (eb init) - set time on window machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running through an issue to connect to the eb instance of aws. 
Whenever I try to log in, it comes back with that issue :

```
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. Signature expired: 20200419T095048Z is now earlier than 20200419T095113Z (20200419T095613Z - 5 min.)
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsignatureexception) that explains that I need to synchronize my local machine with AWS one. 
However, I am not able to find any documentation on doing that process for windows machine.

I am running window 10 and super newbie on AWS.

I try to deploy a flask application on beanstalk but I cannot connect to my EC2 Instance now.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to update your clock on your machine so it is being sync with the internet. 
Window provides several clock server to enable that.

here is an article for Linux system : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/

And how to change time for windows machine : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-time-servers-windows-10