# Can't see my AWS EventBridge rules because signature expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have multiple EventBridge cron events in different regions, that I use only to trigger/run Lambda functions in those regions. Today I can't see any of them in the EventBridge console. In every region, if I open the `Event buses` tab, an error notification appears like `Signature expired: 20220611........ is now earlier than 20220611........ (20220611........ - 5 min.)`, and if I open the `Rules` tab, the rules are simply not there anymore, and the notification is `Failed to get event buses with error: InvalidSignatureException: Signature expired: 20220611........ is now earlier than 20220611........ (20220611........ - 5 min.)`.

Note: I have hidden the second half of the "signatures" with `........` because maybe this is something that is supposed to be private. I don't actually know.

I don't understand how signatures work in AWS, what they do, or where they come from. Goggle didn't help much. I found one question about this here on stack overflow: [Signature expired: is now earlier than error : InvalidSignatureException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsig) but it talks about things I don't understand and doesn't help me figure out what I need to do. But it's really important that those Lambda functions continue to get triggered and run when they need to, without interruptions. Please help me make this go away.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So when you open a website with a browser, some websites can apparently detect the current time set in your PC. So if you change the timezone in your PC, that can cause errors in some cases like this one. The error disappeared, when I opened the AWS website in my phone, or a different PC which had the correct time zone.