# AWS S3 Glacier: Still getting Signature Expired exceptions after trying both manual and synced time/clock on WS 2019

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I am trying to upload some large files (~15 TB) to AWS S3 Glacier and keep getting Signature Expired errors.

I have tried both manually setting a good clock time and then disabling time sync as well as having time and time zone both automatically set by Windows (as suggested here [Signature expired: is now earlier than error : InvalidSignatureException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsignatureexception))

Any time that I observe the clock with my own eyes it seems to be set to the appropriate time.

What else can I do to further identify and/or solve the problem?

**EDIT 1**

**Here's the error message that I'm getting:**

Signature expired: 20231014T151454Z is now earlier than 20231014T151519Z (20231014T152019Z - 5 min.)

**Here's the VB code that references AWSSDK that uploads the file:**

```vb
'4 GB per part
Dim mPartSize = 4L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L

Dim InitiateUpload =
    Function() As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse
        Dim GetInitialRequest =
            Function() As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                Dim mRequest = New Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                With mRequest
                    .VaultName = mVaultName
                    .PartSize = mPartSize
                    .ArchiveDescription = $"{mFileName}_{WhatObjectNamePrefix}"
                End With
                Return mRequest
            End Function

        Return mStorageClient.InitiateMultipartUpload(GetInitialRequest())
    End Function
Dim Upload =
    Function(WhatUploadID As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim mBinaryChecksums = New List(Of String)
        Dim mPosition = 0L

        While mPosition < WhatStream.Length
            Dim mStreamSize = Math.Min(mPartSize, WhatStream.Length - mPosition)
            Dim mTempStream = GlacierUtils.CreatePartStream(WhatStream, mStreamSize)

            Dim mUploadPartRequest = New Model.UploadMultipartPartRequest
            With mUploadPartRequest
                .VaultName = mVaultName
                .UploadId = WhatUploadID
                .Checksum = TreeHashGenerator.CalculateTreeHash(mTempStream)
                .Body = mTempStream

                .SetRange(mPosition, mPosition + mStreamSize - 1)
            End With

            mBinaryChecksums.Add(mUploadPartRequest.Checksum)
            mStorageClient.UploadMultipartPart(mUploadPartRequest)

            mPosition += mStreamSize
        End While

        Return mBinaryChecksums
    End Function
Dim CompleteUpload =
    Sub(WhatUploadID As String, WhatChecksums As List(Of String))
        Dim mCompleteRequest = New Model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        With mCompleteRequest
            .VaultName = mVaultName
            .UploadId = WhatUploadID
            .ArchiveSize = WhatStream.Length.ToString
            .Checksum = TreeHashGenerator.CalculateTreeHash(WhatChecksums)
        End With
        mStorageClient.CompleteMultipartUpload(mCompleteRequest)
    End Sub
Dim AbortUpload =
    Sub(WhatInitialReponse As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse)
        Dim mRequest = New Model.AbortMultipartUploadRequest
        With mRequest
            .UploadId = WhatInitialReponse.UploadId
        End With
        mStorageClient.AbortMultipartUpload(mRequest)
    End Sub

Dim mInitialResponse As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse = Nothing

Try
    mInitialResponse = InitiateUpload()
    Dim mCheckSums = Upload(mInitialResponse.UploadId)
    CompleteUpload(mInitialResponse.UploadId, mCheckSums)
Catch ex As Exception
    If mInitialResponse IsNot Nothing Then Tryer(Sub() AbortUpload(mInitialResponse))
    Throw New Exception($"Failed to upload file {mFileName}", ex)
End Try
```

**EDIT 2**

The link below recommended going async, so I updated the code to use async/await on the 'UploadMultipartPart' function where the exception is being thrown. Async/await keywords were propagated all the way up to Sub Main so no weird deadlock situation.

**Still have the same exception being thrown... Thoughts?**

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-sdk-signature

**EDIT 3**

Updated the code to calculate the tree hash before instantiating the request object in case the signature was made in the constructor and it waited for the hash to complete causing the error. Still no dice

```vb
Dim mPartSize = 4L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L

Dim InitiateUpload =
    Function() As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse
        Dim GetInitialRequest =
            Function() As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                Dim mRequest = New Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                With mRequest
                    .VaultName = mVaultName
                    .PartSize = mPartSize
                    .ArchiveDescription = $"{mFileName}_{WhatObjectNamePrefix}"
                End With
                Return mRequest
            End Function

        Return mStorageClient.InitiateMultipartUpload(GetInitialRequest())
    End Function
Dim Upload =
    Async Function(WhatUploadID As String) As Task(Of List(Of String))
        Dim mBinaryChecksums = New List(Of String)
        Dim mPosition = 0L

        While mPosition < WhatStream.Length
            Dim mStreamSize = Math.Min(mPartSize, WhatStream.Length - mPosition)
            Dim mTempStream = GlacierUtils.CreatePartStream(WhatStream, mStreamSize)

            Dim mTreeHash = TreeHashGenerator.CalculateTreeHash(mTempStream)

            Dim mUploadPartRequest = New Model.UploadMultipartPartRequest()
            With mUploadPartRequest
                .VaultName = mVaultName
                .UploadId = WhatUploadID
                .Checksum = mTreeHash
                .Body = mTempStream

                .SetRange(mPosition, mPosition + mStreamSize - 1)
            End With

            mBinaryChecksums.Add(mUploadPartRequest.Checksum)
            Await mStorageClient.UploadMultipartPartAsync(mUploadPartRequest).ConfigureAwait(False)

            mPosition += mStreamSize
        End While

        Return mBinaryChecksums
    End Function
Dim CompleteUpload =
    Sub(WhatUploadID As String, WhatChecksums As List(Of String))
        Dim mFinalTreeHash = TreeHashGenerator.CalculateTreeHash(WhatChecksums)

        Dim mCompleteRequest = New Model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        With mCompleteRequest
            .VaultName = mVaultName
            .UploadId = WhatUploadID
            .ArchiveSize = WhatStream.Length.ToString
            .Checksum = mFinalTreeHash
        End With
        mStorageClient.CompleteMultipartUpload(mCompleteRequest)
    End Sub
Dim AbortUpload =
    Sub(WhatInitialReponse As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse)
        Dim mRequest = New Model.AbortMultipartUploadRequest
        With mRequest
            .UploadId = WhatInitialReponse.UploadId
        End With
        mStorageClient.AbortMultipartUpload(mRequest)
    End Sub

Dim mInitialResponse As Model.InitiateMultipartUploadResponse = Nothing

Try
    mInitialResponse = InitiateUpload()
    Dim mCheckSums = Await Upload(mInitialResponse.UploadId)
    CompleteUpload(mInitialResponse.UploadId, mCheckSums)
Catch ex As Exception
    If mInitialResponse IsNot Nothing Then Tryer(Sub() AbortUpload(mInitialResponse))
    Throw New Exception($"Failed to upload file {mFileName}", ex)
End Try
```

Comment: Please post the command you're running and the exact error message you're getting. Thank you.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks for your response, just edited with the info. Is it possible that it's taking too long (aka more than 5 minutes) for an individual part to upload so the packets sent after the 5 minute mark for a given AWS part upload get rejected? I'm going to try reducing the part size and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the issue here was that shadow copies (which needed to be taken to be able to read the files getting uploaded) were not being cleared after use and over time, slowed down disk operations to a halt. The slow disk I/O caused the above timing issues.